# Finding the container filesystem (bind mount)

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I've several containers whose volumes are set up like so:

```
    volumes:
        - /opt/App/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}/temp:/usr/local/tomcat/temp
        - /opt/App/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
        - /opt/App/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}/database:/usr/local/tomcat/database
        - /opt/App/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}/backups:/usr/local/tomcat/backups
```

In order to find the volume in the container filesystem, I came up with a not too practical method, so I was wondering if there's anyway to simplify it.

```
docker ps --no-trunc --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}" # finding the container id
docker inspect --format '{{json .Mounts}}' <container_id> # finding the container filesystem's ID
updatedb
locate <id_filesystem> 
cd /var/lib/docker/overlay2/<id_filesystem>/diff/usr/local/tomcat # diretório do Orion
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

I tried using "grep" to look for the container's "UpperDir" from the output of the docker inspect command, but it doesn't work, maybe because it's a .json file.

Maybe I'll come up with a script later, but right now I just want to simplify the process.

Comment: "I tried using "grep"... but it doesn't work, maybe because it's a .json file" `jq` utility is for that.

Comment: As soon as you know that it's within `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`, you don't have to run *updatedb* + *locate* anymore.

Comment: It's risky to manipulate the overlay2 file system outside docker like that, that why it's kinda hard to find. Instead, you've actually specified where you should interact with the volume in your options already (the left side of the colon): `opt/App/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}/temp`

See the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way I found so far is this:

```bash
cd $(dirname $(docker inspect -f '{{ .GraphDriver.Data.UpperDir }}' ${container_name}))
```

So basically using command substitution and also using a script to pass the container name as a flag read from input (overkill? yeah).

Or just using inspect on the image name/id and going to the respective UpperDir.

For [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/), `docker inspect` can be used to bring up information about a container, such as the volume and network. So I used this to automate the process.

I was experimenting with containers and testing a few modifications, hence the original question.

I appreciate the answers and the information about the overlay filesystem, they were very helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).